# Problem in Jquery If Block

Tags: jquery

var htm = $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "./viewforms",
      async: false
     }).responseText;

```
var myObject = eval('(' + htm + ')');

alert(myObject.attributes[0]["type"]);

$("#updateDiv1").html(myObject.attributes[0]["type"]);
alert($("#updateDiv1").text());
l=$("#updateDiv1").text();
alert(l);
if(l =="String")
{
alert("if...");
}
```

In the above code,i m retriving values from database..I m getting correct answer..Now i m comparing my database returned value with the String ..ITs retuning String but dont know why its not entering the IF block..please sugggest me.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try trimming `l` and then comparing it.
http://www.somacon.com/p355.php

Comment: Thanks Yaar .Now its working now.I tried it as..
if(l.trim()=='String')

Answer (score 1):

There may be extra whitespace characters, space, carriage return, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  /* your code */
})
```

around your code.